# Is fair-made lemonade kosher?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, contemporary-halacha, yoreh-deah

I was at a fair the other day and there was a stand selling lemonade with just pressed lemons and cane sugar water. The stand was also making deep fried dougnuts and cold brew coffee.
Does the lemonade need a hashgacha or can we rely on the fact that whatever knife they used was not used for trief? Also, does this issue apply to other pressed fruits? Are there other halachic issues need to be resolved?

Comment: The case is explicit in Shulchan Arukh https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A6%D7%95_%D7%93

Comment: If the sugar water is sitting in the container for more than 24 hours that might be a problem.

Comment: @mroll, wouldn't the taste coming out of the  כלי be נותן טעם לפגם?

Comment: Text the COR hotline - 647-402-1910.

Answer (score 1):

The shulchan aruch in Yoreh Deah 96:4, discusses lemonade made by gentiles and allows it. The Rema explains the leniency and says that there are places in which the minhag was to be Machmir and every location should keep to its minhag.

The Shach (ס"ק כ) has some questions on the rema and as such understands the Rema (in one of the shach's explanations) to try to only be מלמד זכות on the people lenient but that from a sole halacha standpoint it should be assur. Part of the leniency might be connected to an assumption that the knife is only used for the preparation of the lemonade.

Based on the above I would assume that it would make sense to be machmir, because:

1. The Shach's hesitancy
2. Even according to the rema, is the minhag in the mentioned location clear?
3. Assuming that it is a knife solely used for the lemonade (which in itself is highly doubt able), isn't it very likely that the same dishwasher for the knife and other treif keilim. Add the treif food particles in the dishwasher to the mix which make this an even bigger issue.

(As always, thanks @doubleAA)

Comment: The rama says some are machmir about cabbage (?) , but not to be machmir by other things like lemons

Comment: In point 3, what issue could there be with the kli being in the dishwasher with treif keilim? This was the subject of a dispute between the OU and I believe the CRC a few years back about startbucks. Lemaiseh it's difficult to asur especially in a normal dishwasher because the taste would become pagum in the cleaning solution. Rav Aryeh Lebowitz has a "ten" minute halacha about this: https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/757354/rabbi-aryeh-lebowitz/ten-minute-halacha-the-starbucks-controversy/