Does lemon or lime juice need a Hechsher
According to Halacha, does lemon or lime juice from a non Jewish company need a Hechsher? Or no, can it be bought even without a kosher certification?

related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/128664/is-fair-made-lemonade-kosher

Per crc Chicago
Yes. It needs Kosher certification.

For this reason, all pasteurized juices require reliable kosher
certification, even if they do not contain any kosher-sensitive
ingredients.


To be clear, this is a statement of policy by a particular certifying agency and not necessarily halakhah.
